# Popup window in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, popup, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am newbie at android, I am trying show popup window when RecyclerView item clicked but a little bit confused, I looked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383763/how-to-open-a-popup-window-from-an-adapter-class) but cant figure out this Context issue

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Mission> mDataset;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Mission> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.mission_card_item, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.mPointView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPoint());
    holder.mRankView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getRank());

    holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Buton Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}


// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public TextView mPointView;
    public TextView mRankView;
    public Button btnAdd;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        mRankView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_rank);
        mPointView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_point);

        btnAdd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showPopup(itemView);

                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("hello", "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
            }
        });
    }
}


public void showPopup(View view) {
    View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ib_close);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);
}}
```

This is my simple popup window layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#ab2fc4"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a sample popup window."
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="25sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

getActivity() cannot be resolve and gives error, if any one can help, I will be appreciate

Comment: I added an answer in response to your question, let me know if that helps...

Comment: I have added additional content. You can check the code for dialog fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to invoke the method **getActivity()** inside an adapter. The adapter will have no reference to the activity or context. An activity will have the reference to the context and fragment will have a reference to the parent Activity and context (*getActivity() and getContext())*.

Hence make these changes in the code. **First pass the context to the constructor of your Adapter from your Fragment or activity. Then use that context to inflate your layout.**

```
private ArrayList<Mission> mDataset;

private Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Mission> myDataset, Context context) {
    mDataset = myDataset;

    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Next use this instance of your context to inflate your layout.

```
public void showPopup(View view) {
    View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

    // Blah Blah remaining stuff...
}
```

In addition, you could use the same context to inflate the layout in onCreateViewHolder. What you have done is also correct parent.getContext().

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.mission_card_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(v);

}
```

If you just need a popup window. Create a dialog fragment.

```
public class PopupDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Next Launch this dialog fragment. Try this once. You can also customize the dialogfragment to suit your needs.

```
public void showPopup() {
   PopupDialogFragment dialogFragment = new PopupDialogFragment();

   dialogFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), "OpenPopup");
}
```

Comment: I did the changes also in my main fragment I added context like this MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myData, getContext()); but when I run the app and click some of the RecyclerView Item it crashes

Comment: Another thing. I'm not sure why are you trying to inflate another layout as a popup window... Please refer to the the DialogFragment in Android. Maybe DialogFragment is what you are looking for http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                     at com.example.yusuf.firebasedemoapp.MyAdapter.showPopup(MyAdapter.java:104)
                                                                                     at com.example.yusuf.firebasedemoapp.MyAdapter$MyViewHolder$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:91) this lines are Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ib_close); and  showPopup();

Comment: Wait, I'll add the code for the DialogFragment. You don't need to inflate another layout like that.

Comment: Omg, error is not about logic, I made a simple mistake I use ImageButton in popup layout but defined as button, I changed and it worked, thanks a lot